# Get text out of tags with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have been trying to scrape a webpage with Python and Selenium and ran into this problem. Basically, the webpage that I'm scraping shows information in a table with pagination, so I want to get the information from all pages. This is the HTML for the pagination system when I'm at a page that's not the last page (page 2 in this case):

```html
<span class="pagelinks">
   " ["
   <a href="?page=1">First</a>
   "/"
   <a href="?page=2">Previous</a>
   "] "
   <a href="?page=1" title="Go to page 1">1</a>
   ", "
   <strong>2</strong>
   ", "
   <a href="?page=3" title="Go to page 3">3</a>
   " ["
   <a href="?page=3">Next</a>
   "/"
   <a href="?page=3">Last</a>
   "] "
</span>
```

And this is the HTML I get when I reach the last page (page 3 in this case):

```html
<span class="pagelinks">
   " ["
   <a href="?page=1">First</a>
   "/"
   <a href="?page=2">Previous</a>
   "] "
   <a href="?page=1" title="Go to page 1">1</a>
   ", "
   <a href="?page=2" title="Go to page 2">2</a>
   ", "
   <strong>3</strong>
   " [Next/Last]"
</span>
```

In this case, page 3 is selected and appears as `<strong>`, but this changes depending on the current page.

In order to check if I'm at the last page, I want to check if the text "[Next/Last]" is the next text after the `<strong>` tag to stop the *while* loop that retrieves the information, but since this text is out of any tag, I didn’t find any way to check this. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look for `a` with an `href` attribute and `Next` text content. The same can be done for the `Last` text.

With Selenium / Python you can simply use this line:

```py
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@='pagelinks']//a[@href][contains(text(),'Next')]"):
    # Do what you need to do while still not on the last
    # page. Otherwise, this block will be skipped.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! The text actually stays after reaching last page, it's just like "disabled" because it cointains no href. The HTML example is the HTML that I get when reaching last page (page 3 in this case)

Comment: Ah, OK. Can you give us both cases: last page reached and still not HTMLs?

Comment: Sure, already added it

Comment: I see. On non-last page there will be `a` with `href` and `Next` text. Same about `Last`. So, I'm changing my answer accordingly. let me know if now it worked.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, although on screen it's the same text when it has the href it splits it so we can check if it contains the whole text without splits. Thanks!

Comment: No, here I based on the fact that on non-last page it will be `a` with some `href` and `Next` text. But we can also check non-splitted text. I just was not sure about that :)

Comment: Yes, was trying with the split text theory of mine and it seems it always returns true regardless if the text is splitted or not, changing it to your solution now. Thanks!